# How to get a property's name

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

is there a way to get the name of a property of an object?

For example if I have:

```
public class Car : Vehicle 
{
     public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var car = new Car { Make="Ford" };
```

How can I get the name of the Make property in the code?

ie. that `car.Make` has the name `"Make".` So I want to get the string `"Make"`

I'm wanting to do this because I'm wanting to pass the property name to a method.

Update:

I want the name of the property not an array of properties:

Found the answer here:

http://handcraftsman.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/how-to-get-c-property-names-without-magic-strings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want the name of the property not an array of properties:

Found the answer here:

http://handcraftsman.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/how-to-get-c-property-names-without-magic-strings/

Answer (score 3):

```
typeof(Car).GetProperties();
```

and then iterate through the list

Answer (score 3):

```
  Type typ = car.GetType();
  PropertyInfo[] pi = typ.GetProperties();
```

would fetch all properties

You can then do a `.Name` for `pi` elements